# Convert string with millisecond and timezone to Date

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-date

I have string in this format:
2017-04-06T09:29:12.225Z

I need it in date format i tried with:

```
   private Date convertStringToDate(String dateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ");
    Date convertedDate = new Date();
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertedDate;
}
```

But it showing Unparsable error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 7 you can use

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
```

The `X` stands for the *ISO 8601 time zone*, which may be simply `Z` (the zero time zone) or something like `-08`, `-0800` or `-08:00`.
See also the table given in the [javadoc of SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try milliseconds should be capital **S**:

**SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");**

Answer (score 1):

The milliseconds should be capital S, and the Z should be in single quotes:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```